# getting the absolute value of complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

How can I get the absolute value of the following complex number such as
$|(1-i\sqrt{2})^3|$ ?

what is right way to solve it?

Comment: Let $1-i\sqrt{2}=r e^{i\theta}$. get $r$ then cube it.

Comment: First calculate $|1-i\sqrt{2}|$ and then take that value to the power of $3$.

Comment: @LeBtz you can post an answer i'll accept it since I was able to solve it from what you said.

$|(1-i\sqrt{2})^3| = (\sqrt{3})^3 = 3\sqrt{3} $

Comment: I just gave the hint. You can answer your own question now ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More generally, your question could be rephrased as: $|z^n|\stackrel{?}{=}|z|^n$. The answer is **yes**.

To see this, you need to switch from the Cartesian representation of complex number, where $z=a+ib$, to Polar coordinates where $z=re^{i\theta}$:
$$a=r\cos\theta$$
$$b=r\sin\theta$$
$$z=a+ib=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)=re^{i\theta}$$
In this representation, you have: $|z|=r$ and $\arg{z}=\theta$, i.e. $r$ is the distance from the origin to the point $z$ and $\theta$ is the angle $z$ makes with the real axis. You have then:
$$|z^n|=\left|\left(re^{i\theta}\right)^n\right|=\left|r^ne^{in\theta}\right|=r^n$$
$$|z|^n=\left|re^{i\theta}\right|^n=r^n$$
$$\therefore |z^n|=|z|^n$$

And in your particular example:
$$\left|(1-i\sqrt{2})^3\right|=\left|1-i\sqrt{2}\right|^3=(\sqrt{3})^3=3\sqrt{3}$$